# Forbidden header name

Tags: http, header

I'm confused while reading the document about Forbidden header name.[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_header_name)

> These are forbidden, so the user agent retains full control over them

My question is **"Forbidden header name"** is forbidden to do what?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They are forbidden to be set or changed by javascript code, running in a browser sandbox.

Comment: But it says the user agent retains full control over them, since they are forbidden to be set or changed, how can we control over them

Comment: The user agent is the browser itself. The browser has full control, and gives javascript only _some_ control.

Comment: Thank you @Evert for the helpful answer and comment.